Re-exporting an import with gcc/llvm linker
I'm trying to re-create MSVC's behavior of the /export:myfunction=upstreamlib.myfunction linker flag in gcc/llvm (specifically Rust but I think this is a linker question rather than rust) which essentially can re-export/proxy a function call. The target platform is Unix (Linux & Mac).
For example let's say we have upstreamlib.dll and mylib.dll. By using /export:myfunction=upstreamlib.myfunction during linking of mylib.dll, even though the source of mylib doesn't export myfunction, the resulting DLL will have myfunction which windows will search in upstreamlib.dll.
I don't want to rely on the shared library's header to generate function wrappers and I want the solution to be library agnostic (so there's no knowledge of function arguments or return types).
My googling (and AIing) lead me to believe that it's a matter of a linker script but I don't my knowledge around linkers is limited.
I tried --just-symbols=upstreamlib with a linker script with EXPORTS { global: *; } but it didn't do anything.
I also tried forcefully linking against the upstream -lupstreamlib --no-as-needed with the aforementioned export script, but still nothing.

I think it would help if you describe the use case.

I'm creating an "injection library framework" that uses library proxying to mimic the original library. e.g. you want to make XYZ function of originallib.so always return 1 instead of 0, so you rename originallib.so to originallib.so.upstream, compile the project that I'll use the above solution (called injectionforge in github) and name the resulting library originallib.so. the compiled library should just pass-through all function calls apart from XYZ, where it returns 1
